# awk using printf fmt - create xml

Tags: xml, awk, printf

Purpose is to generate XML file based on flat file , using awk. 
I managed to do it by pure coding. (print " .. etc .
But I want a more awk-way by using    printf fmt  .

Input file (there are more  similar lines) - I did not mention header lines (title :  map   entries    mem)  .

```
Mapone        5        10
Maptwo       12        45 
Maptree       8         7
```

Result file should be like :

```
<Map>Mapone</Map>
   <entries>5</entries>
   <mem>10</mem>   
<Map>Maptwo</Map>
   <entries>12</entries>
   <mem>45</mem>   
<Map>Maptree</Map>
   <entries>8</entries>
   <mem>7</mem>
```

Currently i use

```
BEGIN {FS=" " ;

print "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
}

{  Map = $1; }
{  Entry = $2;}
{  mem = $4;}

{
fmt = fmt "\t<Mapname>%s</Mapname>\n";
fmt = fmt "\t\t<Entries>%s</Entries>\n";
fmt = fmt "\t\t<Mem>%s</Mem>\n";

printf fmt, Map, Entry, mem ;

}
```

===>   this script result in error containing 
"awk: There are not enough parameters in printf statement"

Comment: Your `printf` statement should be something like `printf "%s %s %s %s", fmt, Map, Entry, mem ;`. You are missing that.

Comment: You never clear fmt, so after the first line it has too many arguments. Either clear it or print once in an END statement

Comment: @fedorqui That would also fail as they are using `fmt` as the format so don't require the first bit in your example

Comment: @123 oh right, you are correct. I wasn't aware a string could be given to `printf` with all the placeholders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple change

You never clear fmt, so after the first line it has too many arguments

```
BEGIN{
print "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
}

{  Map = $1; }
{  Entry = $2;}
{ mem = $3;  }

{

fmt = "\t<Mapname>%s</Mapname>\n"
#^ this will overwrite the previous fmt, so you won't have too many args.
fmt = fmt "\t\t<Entries>%s</Entries>\n"
fmt = fmt "\t\t<Mem>%s</Mem>\n"

printf fmt, Map, Entry, mem ;

}
```

The above will work although it's still written pretty horribly

I personally would set fmt once in the BEGIN block like below

```
BEGIN{
print "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
fmt = "\t<Mapname>%s</Mapname>\n"
fmt = fmt "\t\t<Entries>%s</Entries>\n"
fmt = fmt "\t\t<Mem>%s</Mem>\n"
}
{
Map = $1
Entry = $2
mem = $3
printf fmt, Map, Entry, mem
}
```

As you can see i have also consolidated the block as there are no arguments for executing it, so it makes (IMO) clearer that it all those commands are executed every line.
I also removed they `;` as the are not required unless you are not using linebreaks and changed mem to `$3` as there are only 3 fields.

Comment: A simple `printf fmt, $1, $2, $3` would be just as clear. Don't need the variables at all.